# How to compare something in a vector to a char?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector

I'm writing a part of tictac toe that evaluates whether space is taken and who is winning.

At first, the compiler told me there is an error: cannot compare pointer and integer (something like that)

```
char board[3][3];
char x="X";
char y="O";

if (board[rowx][colx]!=" ") cout<<"Space taken!";

while (h<3&&Win!=0) {
 if (board[h][0]==board[h][1]==board[h][2]==x) Win=1;
else if (board[h][0]==board[h][1]==board[h][2]==y) Win=2;
}
```

And then I tried to use * and & the error is solved but it doesn't compare.

Comment: Character literals use single quotes.  Strings use double-quotes.

Comment: It is always a good idea to post the full error message that the compiler prints.

Comment: Apart from the issues from mixing string and char types, the while loop in your example looks suspicious as `h` is never incremented. Also, a condition `board[h][0]==board[h][1]==board[h][2]==x` is probably not what you want to do to check if the three tiles contain an x.

Answer (score 0):

```
char board[3][3];
char x='X';
char y='O';

if (board[rowx][colx]!=' ') cout<<"Space taken!";

while (h<3 && Win!=0) {
 if (board[h][0] == board[h][1] && board[h][1] == board[h][2] && board[h][2]==x) 
     Win=1;
  else if (board[h][0] == board[h][1] && board[h][1] == board[h][2] && board[h][2] ==y) 
     Win=2;
}
```

I have not looked into the logic and the code is not tested but you can try this.